# How to access remotly to a mysql server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to access my remote mysql server from my own computer.

I uncommented:

```
bind-address            = 80.10.65.45
```

I added 80.10.65.45 as a server in privilege

```
root    80.10.65.45     yes     ALL PRIVILEGES  yes
```

I'm using Sequel Pro on MacosX to connect via SSH

here is the debug log:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:58517 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:3306
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 58517.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 58517.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 58517 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 58517 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 58519, nchannels 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that the server is listening on 80.10.65.45 but as you have ssh tunneled to the server it will be trying to connect to the server on 127.0.0.1 which isn't being listened on.  If you change it to bind-address = 0.0.0.0 it will listen on all the interfaces, which should fix it.

Comment: If you are using SSH, you may not need for the MySQL server to bind on the public IP address.